# Meteor : remove is not a function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like create global function to remove an item from my collection in Meteor.

My code :

```
Template.adminLayout.events({
    'click .delete': function(e) {

        var collection = $(e.target).data('collection'),
            redirect = $(e.target).data('redirect'),
            id = this._id;

        // Remove request
        collection.remove(id);

        // Redirect
        Router.go(redirect);

    }
});
```

With `collection.remove(id)`, I get this error:

> collection.remove is not a function

If I test with Messages (name of my collection) `Messages.remove(id)`, it works.

Do you have idea why my code does not work?

Comment: when you inspect `collection` in a debugger, or via the console, what is its type?

Comment: Hi Jamiec. collection return "string".

Comment: Well, that's your answer. a string in javascript does not contain a function `remove`! So the next question is, how do you populate `.data('collection')`?

Comment: I would like add my "dynamique collection" on data : `<a href="#" class="delete" data-collection="Messages" data-redirect="messageListAdmin">Delete</a>` EDIT : it's okay, i've add `collection = eval(collection);` and it work ! Thank you Jamiec !

Comment: That's an awful solution, (potentially) opening up your site to hackers. At very least change that to `collection = window[collection]` if its a global object or preferably do not store `Messages` in global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `collection` parameter is a string with the collection name, not the collection itself. You need the actual collection object to perform data operations. If you want to be able to access collection by name, you need to prepare a dictionary yourself. For example:

```
Collections = {};

Collections['Documents'] = Documents = new Mongo.Collection('documents');
```

Then you can use it in your event handler:

```
var collection = Collections[$(e.currentTarget).data('collection')];
```

---

By the way, it's good practice to use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`. It always get you the element you expect, while `e.target` can be one of its descendants.