# Use a var on a helper to change the collection.find() in meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, collections

i have a tab navigation whit a options of collections, and i need fill a table with the elements of this collection, i use this but don't working

```
template.nameTemplate.helpers({
    obj: if(Session.get('tabla')){
         var objCollection = Session.get('tabla');
          return objCollection .find();   
    }else{
          return defaultCollection.find();   
}
});
Template.nameTemplate.events({
    'click .tab':function(e){
         var tablita =  e.currentTarget.children('a').html();
          Session.set(tablita);
}
})
```

the Session.get in a helper work good, i have the exact name of the collection, but don't work. any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have tried to access the collection doesn't make sense. Because you are storing string in `Session` (matching with the collection name). You need to have a `Mongo` Object to make a query. Check out this link and you'll get the workaround of your problem

[Meteor : remove is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688977/meteor-remove-is-not-a-function)